# Something in Term Store Taxonomy is preventing Content Types from publishing

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, taxonomy, term-store

I was creating a new Content Type, and in the process managed to mess up something with the publishing and the Term Store.  I get this error message "Proxy Taxonomy_1y7db0kUVMbatYr8H2I22Q== error." when I try to publish my new Content Type or re-publish an existing Content Type.  This Taxonomy number is the number that shows up as the Available Service Application in my Term Store.  I assume I accidentally changed or deleted a Term Set or Term, but I don't know how to fix it.  Is there a way to figure out what the actual problem is and fix it?